# Find out reason for slow indexing in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have written a script to bulk index a dataset with elasticsearch. It is working as intended, however, if I run the same script on the same dataset on different servers the execution time varies. In the server equipped with SSD, the 2 million documents are done indexing within 10 minutes, however on the one with normal hard disk, it takes up to an hour to complete. Is there a diagnostic tool I can make use of to figure out what causes the slow down?

Some additional information:

- The script is written for Python3, and uses elasticsearch-py module for the bulk indexing
- Both server runs the same operating system (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), the one with slower hard drive has 64GB of RAM, but the one with SSD has half the RAM.

Comment: [SSDs are known to be faster than spinning disks](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html#_storage) when it comes to indexing performance.

Comment: but the difference is very significant, and I wish to find out why, but don't know where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will run into index merges when the large number of records is ingested. That is a process heavily dependent on the speed of the underlying storage. RAM is not really that significant here - it may be more significant when it comes to query performance and stuff you do there. Disk latencies will add up and cause a slow-down compared to the SSD platform.

Therefore, I am not surprised about the SSD speedup. SSD storage is faster than HDD by a factor of 3-8, depending on the manufacturers. If you take into account that HDDs also needs to perform positioning operations for access to different parts of the storage, it is clear that simply using an SDD instead of an HDD can accelerate disk-bound applications by a factor of 10 and more.

Comment: TIL, so there's no way I can tell why it is so horribly slow to my boss, except directing him to this reply?

Comment: Well, if you need hard numbers, I suggest you get "fio" (http://git.kernel.dk/?p=fio.git) and start benchmarking your HDD against the SSD. Write multiple files in sum roughly corresponding to twice the index size you observe in Elasticsearch.That should give you a first impression of performance differences. Then think again about what I wrote.